# Searching for cooking/food ingredients in German

Tags: data-request, food, germany

I am searching for data in German with the names of cooking ingredients.

The example would be: Milch, Rindfleisch, Tomato, Mayonaisse, Knoblauch, Salz

Nutrient factors (fat, calories) would be a plus, but are not required

Comment: Hi @lanenok are you looking for just german or german and the english?

Comment: Hallo @MrR,  only German